# Camunda - where is your API?

Tags: api, rest, cloud, bpmn, camunda

I installed a camunda from the tutorial
https://github.com/berndruecker/camunda-on-pcf
and got it up and running

1. at localhost (http://localhost:8080/app/cockpit/default/#/dashboard)
2. on our PCF (https://*****our-private-pcf*****/app/cockpit/default/#/dashboard)

Then a made a BPMN model via Camunda modeler.

Question 1: Do i choose BPMN Diagram for "Camunda Platform" or for "Camunda Cloud"?

Question 2:
Which value do I have to enter for "REST Endpoint" (Platform) or "Contact Point" (Cloud Self Managed) or "Cluster URL" (Cloud SaaS)?

I tried a lot of combinations of a) localhost oder Cloud URL and b) context root "/engine-rest/" or "/API/" or "/APP/" and so on but none of them works.

Thanks for your thoughts, Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The camunda cockpit uses its own internal REST api. If you additionally want to expose the external api, you must include the [rest-starter dependency](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.camunda.bpm.springboot/camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-rest/7.16.0-alpha5/jar):

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.camunda.bpm.springboot</groupId>
     <artifactId>camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-rest</artifactId>
     <version>...</version>
 </dependency>
```

Then the endpoints mentioned in the docs will match.

Comment: This dependency is allready present in Bernds pom.xml.

Comment: the core of the issue is that "starter-rest" is not working in projects made from Bernds sources. if you try to use cockpit API like me in first aproach your going to find difficulties authenticating an so on. better start new and set up correctly. thanks Jan!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, one day of marveling helps.

First question: Bernds tutorial installs a Spring Boot Camunda and that meens it is a platform, not a cloud solution even if I install it into my cloud.

Second question: the API context root is none of the examples mentioned in documentation. But if you have it up an running: use a browser with developer plugin an watch network traffic. The bundeled web applications "Cockpit", "Tasklist" and "Admin" are NodeJS applications that use the API belonging to this instance.

[Browser showing Camunda Cockpit and Firefox Developer Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVUvD.png)

In this case my URL to API is
http://localhost:8080/api/engine/engine/default/

[Camunda Modeler upload BPMN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aX4ri.png)